# How to get the exact GPU memory usage for Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu, nvidia

I recently started learning Keras and TensorFlow. I am testing out a few models currently on the MNIST dataset (pretty basic stuff). I wanted to know, exactly how much my model is consuming memory-wise, during training and inference. I tried googling but did not find much info.

I came across Nvidia-smi. I tried using *config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True* option but still am not able to use the exact memory python.exe is consuming due to some issues with Nvidia-smi. I know that I could run a separate pass of train and inference, but this is too cumbersome. It is very easy if I could just find the right API to do the job.

Tensorflow being such a well known and well-used library, I am hoping to find a better and faster way to get to these numbers.

Finally, once again my question is:
How to get the exact memory usage for a Keras model during training and inference.

Relevant specs:
OS: Windows 10
GPU: GTX 1050
TensorFlow version: 1.14

Please let me know if any other details are required.

Thanks!

Comment: In TF1 there was function `tf.contrib.memory_stats.MaxBytesInUse()`. Not sure if it is still included in TF2.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at this.

Comment: @Raviteja Narra, Can you please confirm if it is resolved with the comment mentioned above ?